# intellij thymeleaf Namespace th is not bound

Tags: intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I am using IntelliJ IDEA and I have a problem with thymeleaf namespaces. I have created employee form which I am including into other templates so I did not specified namespaces but it works fine when I run my application. Is there any way to change this behaviour. I like to have an auto-complete :-)

**Namespace 'th' is not bound example:**

[image: Namespace 'th' is not bound]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Also, if you are using `Spring` you should use the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
     <title>Hello</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The difference is in the `DOCTYPE`.
See [Intellij Idea: Thymeleaf namespace unkown](http://kamwo.me/intellij-idea-thymeleaf-namespace-unkown/)

Comment: Is there a new dtd for spring5?

Comment: @axiopisty good question. Here https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf.github.com/tree/master/dtd nothing, concerning sprin 5.

Comment: In versions of Intellij > 2017.3 you should not need a doctype (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804086/474034)

Answer (score 13):

To enable auto completion and IDE support for Thymeleaf, make sure you have enabled the Thymeleaf plugin.

`File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Config Plugins` -> tick `Thymeleaf`

[image: screenshot of plugin window]

Also add the namespace in the root tag

`<html .... xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`

Comment: I can't find this configuration in Intellij 2016.

Comment: This applies for Ultimate version only, not Community.

Answer (score 7):

There's no harm defining your fragments in a well formed document (including a `html`, `head`, `body` etc). In fact this is how the [Thymeleaf Documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments) does it.

This way you can specify the thymeleaf namespace so you get autocomplete, and you can also view your fragments by themselves in the browser, which is useful for prototyping.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org"` into the html tag helped me. So now it looks like below:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      lang="en">
<head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intellij IDEA, you can also use the JBLHtmlToThymeleaf plugin. With this plugin, you can simply right click on your HTML file and add the required namespace.

Operation steps for this: (on the IDE)

`File`->`Settings`->`Plugins`->`Marketplace` and search `JBLHtmlToThymeleaf`

[Install JBLHtmlToThymeleaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oy7x.png)

After the installation is complete, right click on a desired html file and select JBLHtmlToThymeleaf.

[Right click the HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhHCe.png)

After the process is complete, you will see that the namespace `xmlns: th = "http://www.thymeleaf.org"` has been added automatically.

Bonus: Also if you want to use Spring Security in HTML file, don't forget to add `xmlns: sec = "http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"`.