# Spring boot + thymeleaf in IntelliJ: cannot resolve vars

Tags: java, spring, web, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I'm writing a short web form application using spring boot and thymeleaf on IntelliJ, but it seems that in the html file, all fields in the model cannot be resolved. Here is my code:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addNewPost(@Valid Post post, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            return "index";
        }
        model.addAttribute("title",post.getTitle());
        model.addAttribute("content",post.getContent());
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Model Class:

```
public class Post {

    @Size(min=4, max=35)
    private String title;

    @Size(min=30, max=1000)
    private String content;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

Then is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">

    <title>Spring Framework Leo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Spring Boot and Thymeleaf</h3>


    <form action="#" th:action="@{/}"  th:object="${post}" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{title}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('title')}" th:errors="*{title}">Title error message</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Content:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">Content error message</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit">Submit post</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

There are always red lines under "post", "title"  and "content", but I don't know how to solve it. Is it a problem of IntelliJ or just a problem of my code?

Comment: This should be fixed in IntelliJ 2013.3, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## Prerequisites

- Thymeleaf plugin is installed
- The `html` element has an XML namespace declaration for `th` that is set   to `http://www.thymeleaf.org` (with `www.`), for example:

  ```
  <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  ```

## IntelliJ version >= 2017.3

Detection should work automatically. However, some people complain that it still does not work for them), the issue [IDEA-132738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738) should be fixed (@FloatOverflow: "I confirm that in version 2017.3 build 25.Oct.2017 the problem has been solved"):

> Status 2017.3
>
> Support for Spring Boot autoconfigured MVC applications is complete, all bundled autoconfiguration view types are supported.
>
> Fix versions: 2017.3

If variables are not automatically detected you can still add the `@thymesVar` annotation as shown below.

## IntelliJ version < 2017.3

It is, as [Andrew wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38720588/2886891), a known error [IDEA-132738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738). There is a workaround how to get rid of the error marks in the IDE. IntelliJ also supports the semi-automatic generation of the below mentioned code:

> You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut to invoke intention "Declare external variable in comment annotation" in order to get rid of "unresolved model attribute" in your views.

Add the following code to your `html` file:

```
<!--/* Workaround for bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738 -->
    <!--@thymesVar id="post" type="your.package.Post"-->
    <!--@thymesVar id="title" type="String"-->
    <!--@thymesVar id="content" type="String"-->
<!--*/-->
```

If you use extensions objects constructed automatically by ThymeLeaf, such as `#temporals` from `thymeleaf-extras-java8time` for conversion of `java.time` objects:

```
<span th:text="${#temporals.format(person.birthDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></span>
```

and IntelliJ cannot resolve them, use similar code, and just add `#` in front of the object name:

```
<!--@thymesVar id="#temporals" type="org.thymeleaf.extras.java8time.expression.Temporals"-->
```

Comment: I confirm that in version 2017.3 build 25.Oct.2017 the problem has been solved!

Comment: @FloatOverflow I'm running 2017.3 and my objects are still underlined. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? For example, in below code both `test` and `name` are underlined.

`<h1 th:text="'Thanks for helping us test, ' + ${test.name} + '!'"></h1>`

Comment: @justinraczak I recommend you to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and report it to Jetbrains. You may either add it to the above mentioned issue, or create a new one.

Comment: The answer is helpful with version IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 Ultimate

Comment: In 2019.3.2 the bug still exists.

Comment: @workerjoe I recommend you to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and report it to Jetbrains. You may either add it to the above mentioned issue, or create a new one.

Answer (score 54):

## Update

**TL;DR:** skip to accepted answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804086/474034

As mentioned in the comments by multiple people, this solution is not correct. The Thymeleaf documentation (see http://thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html), have in all their examples a version with `www.` included:

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

See also the [Standard-Dialect.xml](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/resources/org/thymeleaf/xml/thymeleaf/Standard-Dialect.xml) on Github, which declares `namespace-uri` as:

```xml
namespace-uri="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
```

## Original Answer

I had two different portions of code: the first was showing the error and the second was not doing it.
I observed that there is a difference in the **xmlns:th** attribute.

**First Page: Not working!**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

**Second Page: Working!**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
```

I removed the **www.** and it works for me!

Comment: This is what worked for me and i'm using IntelliJ 2018+

Comment: An unbelievable solution - but it works. I'm using IntelliJ 2019.1.3 UE.

Comment: This removes the underline of the variables, because the `th` namespace becomes invalid at all. With the above "solution" all `th` attributes should have an error now:  `Attribute th:**** is not allowed here.`

Comment: lul, thanks for this xD Solved it for me with 2019.something, too

Comment: This looks suspicious. It is against the Thymeleaf documentation (https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html), where they have in all their examples `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`. You can see it also here: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/resources/org/thymeleaf/xml/thymeleaf/Standard-Dialect.xml: `namespace-uri="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

Comment: As @RiZKiT said, by doing that you just broke your namespace definition... Same results would be if you put there: xmlns:th="http://mybrokenuri.org">

Comment: I'm agree with @RiZKiT. This solution is not Correct!

Comment: @RiZKiT, and yet, it works for me with IntelliJ 2019.1

Comment: I agree with @RiZKiT.

Answer (score 17):

This is a problem with IntelliJ: [IDEA-132738](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738).

Basically IntelliJ is unable to locate the model variables when Spring Boot has been used to autoconfigure everything.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 2017.2 and this issue still exists in the IDE. This is so dominating when I visit my html files. Why JetBrains guys haven't yet fixed this for Thymeleaf support?

Comment: @MAC This should be fixed in IntelliJ 2013.3, see my edited answer.

Comment: @HonzaZidek I still have it in 2019.2 for some reason... Also, I've checked thier bug tracker website, and it seems that there are still users who have the smae problem with newer versions like 2017, etc.

Comment: @HaimLvov I recommend you to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and report it to Jetbrains. You may either add it to the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738, or create a new one.

Comment: @HaimLvov I think they will ignore your comment under IDEA-132738. See what Yann Cebron  commented on 13 Nov 2017 10:08:
PLEASE **stop adding comments** to this issue. 
If you encounter problems, please **file a NEW ISSUE with attached minimal sample project**. Please note that static web resource directories currently still have to be setup manually in Web Facet once, see IDEA-121038.

Answer (score 13):

I want to add one more thing. As stated above, the issue has been fixed in **IntelliJ 2017.3**. I can also confirm this.

However, I noticed that this is only true if you define all your attributes **directly** inside the responsible controller function, like e.g. this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinput")
public String showUserForm(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("method", "post");
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "userform";
}
```

If you are using a sub-function in which you define the model attributes (see **Example** below), IntelliJ can still not find the attributes in the HTML template.

**Example**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/userinput")
public String showUserForm(Model model){
    return doIt(model);
}

private String doIt(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("method", "post");
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "userform";
}
```

So, always make sure you put your code directly inside the view function!

Comment: And/Or if your RequestMappings are in Kotlin, the IDE doesn't see the attributes much like using the private method.

Comment: @Chris.Jenkins do you know if there is any way around this problem? I just ran into this issue.

Comment: I can confirm that as of IntelliJ 2019.3.2 Ultimate, this workaround (using `model.addAttribute()`) is still necessary to get IntelliJ to recognize the form object.  Or the other workaround suggested by Honza Zidek, using a `@thymesVar` comment annotation.

Answer (score 5):

Manually enabling it, worked for me in Intellij 2018.1.6 Ultimate Edition. Steps followed

1. Open the Project tool window (e.g. View | Tool Windows | Project).
2. Right-click the project or the module folder and select Add
       Framework Support.
3. In the left-hand pane of the Add Frameworks
       Support dialog that opens, select the Thymeleaf checkbox.

Official reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/thymeleaf.html#0c8052be

Comment: I'm here because the Add Frameworks Support dialog doesn't show thymeleaf, only groovy and maven

Comment: This is what ultimately worked for me.   One thing to note, once I added the framework support I had to do FIle->Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I had the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Once I removed these properties, the spring mvc mappings are detected by Intellij again (in the Ultimate version, I'm using 2018.1). Also the thymeleaf objects are working now.

I used these properties to support fast development where a refresh would reload the thymeleaf template files.

To solve this issue, I use the following -D option in my run configuration of my spring boot application to tell spring boot where my property files are during development:

```
-Dspring.config.location=/dev/application/conf/application.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more interesting situation ,if you DONT return directly the object from your controller ,Intellij will not recognize the variable ,but she will still work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score 1):

This problem comes from thymeleaf web link.

The problem:`xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"`

[image: This is problem link:]

[image: This is error area:]

The solution: `xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"`

[image: Solution link]

[image: Error is gone]

Comment: now you have warning about invalid th:style attribute, so not really solution

Answer (score 0):

For those who come from ReactJS and want to use Springboot as a backend.

I forgot to add html boilerplate code in the html, that's why I'm seeing this error. don't forget adding boilerplate code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me on Ultimate 2021.2.1.

In one `@GetMapping` method, I used `@ModelAttribute('transactionForm')`.  The Thymeleaf page for that method didn't have errors.

But in another `@GetMapping` method, I didn't use `@ModelAttribute('newCustomerForm')`.  The Thymeleaf page for that method had the errors.  When I added the `@ModelAttribute` to the method, the errors went away.  And when I took it out, the errors came back.

I know Spring MVC doesn't require the `@ModelAttribute` if the name of the model is the same as the class name.  So I shouldn't have to do this, and I'm only doing this to appease the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it (ultimate 2021.3.2).
Intellij has a hard time guessing the type of the attribute(s).

Keep **www** in the namespace xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" otherwise Intellij won't parse thymeleaf tags

If you initialize one model in a controler,

- don't use a method's return, declare a variable

  ```
  String titre=post.getTitle();
  model.addAttribute("title",titre);
  ```
- don't add attributes through sub methods, keep it in the main block

  ```
  @GetMapping("/book")
  public String ver(Model model) {
  ...
  model.addAttribute("title", title);
  return "frontpage";
  }
  ```
- and don't use complex operator like the ternary one

  ```
  model.addAttribute("titles", titles.size() > 0 ? titles : null);
  ```

If you initialize 2 or 3 models in you controler,
don't push null values

```
model.addAttribute("employees", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was resolve like following
click **Alt + Enter**

Lets try it!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In spring boot + thymeleaf, after adding a custom bean, everything worked. Hope it helps someone!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Z6l.png

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with using another spring-boot-parent version

(2.3.2 working version) previously was 2.7.15 (not working)

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

All problems can be fixed this bean related to Thymeleaf

```java
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    templateResolver.setCheckExistence(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This feature is supported in the Ultimate edition only.

[Click here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/thymeleaf.html) for more details

Comment: This does not provide a complete answer to the question, although it may be relevant. When you have earned enough reputation, you will be able to post information such as this as comments to the question or other answers, but you should not post answers unless they address the question that was asked directly.

Comment: this is look like Comment. this not right way to paste your answer refer how to write good answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer