# Intellij cannot resolve variables of thymeleaf templates in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710585/spring-boot-thymeleaf-in-intellij-cannot-resolve-vars) said the problem is fixed already, but it seems that I still have the problem even I have the latest version of IntelliJ Ultimate.

I have `implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf"` in my gradle setting.

[image]

The application works fine, but I want to be able to use [The Navigate to Declaration feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/thymeleaf.html) provided by IntelliJ. I already have `thymeleaf-spring` module in my project.

Comment: Please report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach a sample project to reproduce the issue.