# I can not find the variable thymeleaf. Why?

Tags: thymeleaf

I can not find variable for building simple for-each-loop in Thymeleaf template.

```
<div th:each="md:${mds}">
  <a th:text="${md}"></a>
</div>
```

Cannot resolve 'md' by IDEA.

Here is my server code:

```java
  @GetMapping("/example.html")
    private String mds2book(ModelMap model) throws IOException {
        BookConfig bookConfig = Util.readBookConfig(null);
        List<Md> mds = Util.readMds();
        model.addAttribute("mds", mds);
        return "mds2book";
    }
```

If you know where the error is, I think, I need your help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding html header：

```html
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Success!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710585/spring-boot-thymeleaf-in-intellij-cannot-resolve-vars) is answer.